# Spring Security: How to integrate two apps with individual spring security configuration?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have 2 apps, running as independent springboot application.
App1 & App2.

User enters credentials on UI of App1, which are routed through angular js.

```
$http.post('/login', $.param(self.credentials), {
      headers : {
        "content-type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      }
}
```

Spring security successfully intercepts this request. After intercepting this request, I make a post request to App2(running on port 8018)

```
// implementation of authentication provider:
public Authentication authenticate(final Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {    
    Authentication auth = null;   
    MultiValueMap<String, Object> params = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    params.set("username", "user"); // for testing purpose
    params.set("password", "user"); // for testing purpose
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    HttpHeaders reqHead = new HttpHeaders();
    reqHead.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());
    ResponseEntity response = restTemplate.postForEntity("http://localhost:8018/login/process",
            new HttpEntity<>(params, reqHead), MyClass.class);
```

However Spring security in App2 is not able to intercept this request correctly. All I get is 302(null).

```
DEBUG 12144 --- [nio-8010-exec-1] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Setting request Accept header to [application/json, application/*+json]
DEBUG 12144 --- [nio-8010-exec-1] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Writing [{username=[user], password=[user]}] as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" using [org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter@2fc281c1]
DEBUG 12144 --- [nio-8010-exec-1] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : POST request for "http://localhost:8018/login/process" resulted in 302 (null)
```

*(MyClass is just a class containing httpstatus and Object data.)*

My app2 security configuration:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/welcome").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.csrf().disable();
        // http.httpBasic();
        http.formLogin()
    }
```

If I change

```
antMatchers("/welcome").permitAll()
```

to

```
antMatchers("/welcome","/login/**").permitAll()
```

then request successfully bypasses security and reached my controller.
So I am assuming that spring security is able to intercept but there is some config I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your config in App2 says: "everybody is allowed to visit /welcome endpoint; but only authenticated ones (with form authentication) are allowed to visit all the other pages".

So when you make a request to `/login/process`, Spring Security in App2 redirects that request to the login page.

If you want this request to be handled like a 'trusted' request, you have to instruct Spring Security in App2 accordingly. For example, you could add Basic Authentication to your 'privileged' URLs. This can be done with a technique described here: [Combining basic authentication and form login for the same REST Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33739359/combining-basic-authentication-and-form-login-for-the-same-rest-api)

Then, you'd have to add Basic authentication to your requests, an example is here: http://www.baeldung.com/how-to-use-resttemplate-with-basic-authentication-in-spring

Another approach which requires less code but forces you to manually build Authorization header is described here: http://springinpractice.com/2013/10/02/quick-tip-basic-authentication-with-spring-resttemplate