# Spring Security configuring two different authentication for two different url

Tags: rest, spring-boot, spring-security

I am developing a web application with spring security which will be used by web users as well as android users. Currently I have configured `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/","/about","/contact","/v1/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/admin/otp").hasRole("PRE_AUTH_USER")
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAnyRole("SuperAdmin","BackOffice")
            .antMatchers("/admin/dashboard/**").hasAnyRole("BankAdmin","CallAdmin")
            //.antMatchers("/api/**").hasRole("FieldPerson")
            .anyRequest().authenticated();

    http.formLogin()
            .loginPage("/admin/login")
            .permitAll()
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin/otp", true)
            .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/admin/login")
            .permitAll();

    http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/error/403");
}

@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider(){
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12));
    return authProvider;
}

@Autowired
public void registerAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).and().authenticationProvider(authProvider());
}
}
```

This works perfect, but I want to use the same configuration for rest api authentication without any otp verification screen (basically its a 2FA with GOOGLE Authenticator for web users). So I wanted to configure just database authentication for android users. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33739359/combining-basic-authentication-and-form-login-for-the-same-rest-api) solution but I failed with issue of `user is not anonymous`. Basically I just want to configure whenever user hit `/api/**` it should be authorised.

Comment: You have to show your Spring Security configuration. AFAIK your error message is not possible with the configuration in the linked question.

Comment: @dur you mean to say another configuration according to link I have mentioned??

Comment: You wrote: *I tried this solution but I failed with issue of user is not anonymous.* But the solution from the link cannot produce such kind of error. So we need to see your configuration. The one you tried.