# Spring Security, disable formLogin() for REST requests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-rest

I'm using Spring Boot, Spring Security, Spring Data REST, Hibernate.
I'm creating a REST API server.

I configured security to access my REST API as:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private TenantFilter tenantFilter;


    @Autowired
    public void configureAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(this.userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(User.PASSWORD_ENCODER);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter jwtTokenFilter() throws Exception {
        return new JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public CookieAuthFilter cookieAuthFilter() throws Exception {
        return new CookieAuthFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomWebAuthenticationDetailsSource customWebAuthenticationDetailsSource() {
        return new CustomWebAuthenticationDetailsSource();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                //********************************************************************
                // PERMIT OPTIONS
                //********************************************************************
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()

                //********************************************************************
                //WEBSOCKET
                //********************************************************************
                .antMatchers("/socket/**").permitAll()

                .antMatchers("/images/**").permitAll()

                .antMatchers("/resources/templates/**").permitAll()

                .antMatchers("/api/v1/notifications/**").permitAll()

                //********************************************************************
                // SWAGGER
                //********************************************************************
                .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs", "/swagger-accounts/configuration/ui", "/swagger-accounts", "/swagger-accounts/configuration/security",
                        "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**", "/swagger-resources/**").permitAll()


                .antMatchers("/api/v1/").permitAll()

                .antMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/formLogin/**").permitAll()

                .antMatchers("/api/v1/logout").permitAll()

                .antMatchers("/api/v1/agents/verifyEmail").permitAll()

                .antMatchers("/api/v1/agents/**/verificationToken").permitAll()

                .antMatchers("/api/v1/agents/**/resetPassword").permitAll()

                .antMatchers("/api/v1/agents/**/verifyPasswordReset").permitAll()

                .antMatchers("/api/v1/agents/**/changePassword").permitAll()

                .antMatchers("/api/v1/errors/**").permitAll()

                .antMatchers("/api/v1/verifyCaptcha").permitAll()

                .antMatchers("/api/v1/ping").permitAll()

                .antMatchers("/api/v1/tenants/**").permitAll()

                // all other endpoints are authenticated
                .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()

                // global settings
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable();

       http.formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll();


        // Custom JWT based security filter
        http.addFilterBefore(tenantFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http.addFilterBefore(cookieAuthFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        http.headers().cacheControl().disable();
    }
}
```

The goal I want to get is:

- show a form login when the user try to access to the url like http://myhost/swagger-ui.html#/ in order to be able to use swagger easily
- avoid form login when the server is called with a REST call (through Angular or Postman or whatever). In fact, otherwise if the auth fails, the server replies with the html code of the login page

is there a way to accomplish this with Spring, without turning off formLogin()?

Answer (score 2):

Other configuration looks fine

If you notice swagger related urls are also are marked as `permitAll().`

Just remove permitAll part of swagger and add this in last as authenticated() something like this

```
.antMatchers("/v2/api-docs", "/swagger-accounts/configuration/ui", "/swagger-accounts", "/swagger-accounts/configuration/security",
                        "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**", "/swagger-resources/**").authenticated()
```

For REST calls just see if they are added in  `permitAll()`

**Also Note:** The order of the rules matters and the more specific rules should go first

eg

```
.antMatchers("/admin/**").authenticated()
.antMatchers("/admin/login").permitAll()
```

Here `/admin/login` will also be authenticated.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Combining basic authentication and form login for the same REST Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33739359/combining-basic-authentication-and-form-login-for-the-same-rest-api), I believe it meets your requirement.

The only thing I think you may need to change is in `ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter` since you only ask 403, the content should look like below (`hasRole(String...)` could be replaced by `authenticated()` if you don't like it's too strict).

```java
http.antMatcher("/api/**").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasRole("ADMIN")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if or how you solved this, but i was looking for something similar. So for anybody who is also looking for this here are my thoughts:

You an *configure 2  HttpSecurity elements*. So you have  extends the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter 2 times.
Make your endpoints like this:

- '/view/**/*' for everything that requires form login
- '/api/**/*' for everything that juse needs a 403

Then in one security config confiugre that /view/ with .formlogin()
In the other security don't configure the .formlogin()

An example of 2 securityConfigs in one app can be found here:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-two-login-pages
However in that article they use it to show 2 different login pages, you could just use this to not show a formlogin in one case...