# Spring Security - multiple security config requirement - adding basic auth to existing REST API Authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a REST API with the following security config -

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Value("${auth0.audience}")
    private String audience;

    @Value("${auth0.issuer}")
    private String issuer;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) {
        try {
            http.authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/purch").authenticated()
                    .antMatchers("/purch2").authenticated();

            JwtWebSecurityConfigurer
                    .forRS256(audience, issuer)
                    .configure(http);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new AuthenticationException(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I had added Swagger docs for this REST API and I am trying to protect the swagger docs using HTTP Basic Auth using [this example](https://blog.appandgeek.com/enable-authentication-basic-auth-on-swagger-ui-using-spring-security/)

Hence, I updated the above WebSecurityConfig with `@Order(1)` and added a new WebSecurityConfig with `Order(2)` as shown below -

```java
@Configuration
@Order(2)
public class SwaggerSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String[] AUTH_LIST = { //
            "**/v2/api-docs", //
            "**/configuration/ui", //
            "**/swagger-resources", //
            "**/configuration/security", //
            "**/swagger-ui.html", //
            "**/webjars/**" //
    };

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(AUTH_LIST).authenticated().and().httpBasic();
    }

    //@Override
    @Autowired
    protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password(passwordEncoder().encode("password")).roles("USER")
                .and()
                .withUser("admin").password(passwordEncoder().encode("admin")).roles("USER", "ADMIN");
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

This does not seem to have any effect and is NOT prompting for the basic auth credentials.
I tried several combinations of answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33739359/combining-basic-authentication-and-form-login-for-the-same-rest-api), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35363924/java-spring-security-config-multiple-authentication-providers) and [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#multiple-httpsecurity)... But I am unable to get this working!

I was able to get the standalone `Order(2)` spring web security config working as expected, just not in combination with `Order(1)` security config.

As you can see from my question, I am not an expert with Spring Security and tried debugging this as much as I can! its time I sought for help after losing couple of hours on this. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

**Update based on comments:**
I already tried combining the Web Security Config classes similar to what is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35405109/829542) or [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-multiple-auth-providers). The outcome is that my original REST API which was protected with "Authorization Header" bearer authentication is now overriden with Basic Auth.

May be, my question is - how do I make sure that one Web security config does not override another?

```java
@Configuration
@Order(2)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Value("${auth0.audience}")
    private String audience;

    @Value("${auth0.issuer}")
    private String issuer;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) {
        try {
            http.authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/purch").authenticated()
                    .antMatchers("/purch2").authenticated();

            JwtWebSecurityConfigurer
                    .forRS256(audience, issuer)
                    .configure(http);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new AuthenticationException(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        private static final String[] AUTH_LIST = { //
                "/v2/api-docs", //
                "/configuration/ui", //
                "/swagger-resources", //
                "/configuration/security", //
                "/swagger-ui.html", //
                "/webjars/**" //
        };

        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
               .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/purch/**").permitAll().and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(AUTH_LIST)
                    .authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .httpBasic();
        }

        @Autowired
        protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                    .withUser("user").password(passwordEncoder().encode("password")).roles("USER")
                    .and()
                    .withUser("admin").password(passwordEncoder().encode("admin")).roles("USER", "ADMIN");
        }

        @Bean
        public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you refer to the answers here -> stackoverflow.com/a/35405109/905494, you will see that you need the same AuthenticationManagerBuilder to configure all your authentication providers. So basically combining the security config classes into one and configuring the authentication providers will probably solve your problem. See this example too: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-multiple-auth-providers

Comment: @tksilicon - thanks for responding. I already tried this and the outcome was that my original REST API header based authentication was getting overriden with Basic Auth that I added. Updated the code above with my combined implementation.

Comment: Spring has an [own section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/jc.html#multiple-httpsecurity) in their reference which showcases how to setup multiple `HttpSecurity` configurations

Comment: @Satya I think the two ways to go about it is having multisecurity or using the same authenticationbuilder. From the name,  authenticationbuilder should be used when you do not want to order the authentication. Probably the first one passed becomes the order 1 but with multsecurity, you can order it.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have mixed up contents gleaned from different sources. Please try a configuration like below.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    // Firs this configuration will apply since the order is 1
    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            // configure auth modes and path matchers
        }
    }

    // Since there is no @Order annotation, this will be checked at last
    @Configuration
    public static class MvcWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            // configure auth modes and path matchers
        }
    }
}
```