# Combining BasicAuth() with FormLogin() for different paths

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I have this code for activating basicAuth() on my api

I also have some html pages on the same project and i need all requests for those pages to be redirected to formLogin()

the login page is placed on the root directory and the internal pages are placed in user directory

so in summary

all requests to http://localhost:8080/* should ask for form login

all requests to http://localhost:8080/api/* should ask for basic auth

```
package com.project.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user")
                .password("{noop}password")
                .roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").hasRole("USER")
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33739359/combining-basic-authentication-and-form-login-for-the-same-rest-api

Comment: the chosen answer has this comment
This does not work anymore with Spring Security 5.0.8. Any request to /api/** with be redirected to the form login